# Snowflake JavaScript Procedure Array Include

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to check if KEY is present in a customer array variable using includes.

```
var arr1 = ['FirtName'];

for (var key of Object.keys(json) ){
if ( arr1.includes(key) ){
//Perform something
}}
```

Upon observing the behaviour it seems includes function is not matching entire key.

Example: key="Name" is also satisfying the IF condition. Ideally it should not match.

Is there any issue with Snowflake Javascript function or there is any other comparison technique.

Tried arr1.IndexOf also and thats also not working.

Comment: please post working examples of your problem and not just code fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It could be as simple as a typo: `FirtName`? Is `json` an object, or is it JSON? You should probably rename that variable if it's an actual object.

Comment: If your ``json`` its a JSON then it should have this structure in order to work as you expected ``{"FirtName":"test"}``

Comment: @MiguelHidalgo Yes I think i was passing the data incorrectly. Thanks